# Snowflake's LAG function bug when current row's value is NULL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using `LAG` function to get "previous" price of the item, and it is working fine, except the case when the current price is NULL, in which case it returns the very last price in the section

```sql
SELECT s.id as sale_id,
       COALESCE(s.property_id, c.property_id) as c_property_id,
       COALESCE(c.sale_date, s.created_at) as sale_date,
       c.price,
       lag(c.price, 1, NULL) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by c_property_id order by sale_date) as previous_price
FROM "CLOSINGS" c FULL OUTER JOIN "SALES" s on c.sale_id = s.id
WHERE c_property_id = xxx
ORDER BY sale_date
```

And here is what I am getting as a result - please note the `990000` as previous_price on the fourth row

```
SALE_ID C_PROPERTY_ID   SALE_DATE   PRICE   PREVIOUS_PRICE
         xxx            1997-10-06  370000          NULL
         xxx            2000-02-22  550000          370000
         xxx            2003-09-05  675000          550000
mmmmmmm  xxx            2019-11-26  NULL            990000
         xxx            2019-12-17  1100000         675000
nnnnnnn  xxx            2020-06-16  990000          1100000
```

Comment: You are asking to IGNORE NULLS, so it'll ignore the current record and go to the previous value.  If you want it to be NULL, then don't ignore the NULLs.  Am I missing your question?

Comment: I think either you are, or I am missing what the `INGORE` means. What I want is `previous price` to get the last non-null value from records above. From the documentation, IGNORE NULLS means ignoring nulls when shifting to the previous price. For example, the row below the last one shows the correct value (it skips the NULL before it), which is what I want. for the `mmmmmm` row, I also want to get `675000`, not `999000`, (which is definitely an unrelated value anyway)

Comment: Without the raw data, it is hard to determine where you are seeing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue but as I see, LAG works as expected. Maybe there is something else with your query. Can you share some sample data?

```
with price_data as (
select * from values
('xxx','1997-10-06',370000 ),
('xxx','2000-02-22',550000 ),
('xxx','2003-09-05',675000 ),
('xxx','2019-11-26',null ),
('xxx','2019-12-17',1100000 ),
('xxx','2020-06-16',990000 ) tmp(C_PROPERTY_ID,SALE_DATE,PRICE))
select C_PROPERTY_ID,SALE_DATE,PRICE,
lag( PRICE, 1, NULL) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by c_property_id order by sale_date) as previous_price
FROM price_data
order by sale_date;


+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+
| C_PROPERTY_ID | SALE_DATE  |  PRICE  | PREVIOUS_PRICE |
+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+
| xxx           | 1997-10-06 |  370000 |           NULL |
| xxx           | 2000-02-22 |  550000 |         370000 |
| xxx           | 2003-09-05 |  675000 |         550000 |
| xxx           | 2019-11-26 |    NULL |         675000 |
| xxx           | 2019-12-17 | 1100000 |         675000 |
| xxx           | 2020-06-16 |  990000 |        1100000 |
+---------------+------------+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: can you expand on your note? how does partitioning/ordering on pre-computed columns change the outcome (and what  can I do about it, given I need this outer join and coalesce results?)

Comment: Yes you are right. It might be not related, but now I noticed that you use different columns even for prices. PRICE is c. price, but you get c.closing_price from previous row for PREVIOUS_PRICE.

Comment: I don't know why I put question marks every where :)

Comment: yeah sorry that's was me trying to simplify the query for reading, fixing that

Comment: Actually thanks, now when I made an explicitly different column for  `coalesce` dates and both partition on it and sort on it, everything seems to match up